# How to pass a List of delegates as a parameter (in a "pretty" way)

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a Constructor that is getting too big (12 parameters).
All of these parameters are either Actions (Action, Action) or a generic delegate (which i have about 8 of).

How can I pass a List of delegates and therefore reduce the number of parameters of my constructor in a way that is still readable? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
// Controller //
var methods = new List<StrategyDelegate>()
{
    model.OpenWindowMethod,
    model.CloseWindowMethod
};
View(methods);

// View //
public delegate void StrategyDelegate();
private StrategyDelegate _openWindow;
private StrategyDelegate _closeWindow;

View(List<StrategyDelegate> methodsToCall)
{
    _openWindow = methodsToCall.Find("model.OpenWindowMethod"); ???
    _closeWindow = methodsToCall[1]; ???
}
```

But I don't like neither of these approaches since one of them uses strings and the other one I have to know the order of the list, and if I remove one of the methods I might have to reorder the whole thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can make a new class to hold all your parameters, or you can use the builder pattern.

Comment: the problem is that my "View" doesn't communicate with any other class, only through events. I'll check out the builder pattern though, thanks!

Comment: What I mean by class, is that you have the Controller set the parameters in a class as the delegates you want to use in View, so you don't need to use the string search or have to know the order in the array.  The builder pattern could help by making the constructor not seem so big because you can do something like this `some_obj().setA(1).setB(4).setC("hi")...`.  You can add/remove a delegate whenever you want, and you will have an easy time refactoring.

Comment: Why does your constructor needs 12 parameters? The builder pattern is ideal for avoiding lots of parameters. But I think you should look at these parameters and what they have in common, you might need to combine some, because they are closely connected. I should not recommend passing a list, if something is inserted or removed, the whole method will execute wrong methods. At least make it a dictionary, where the keys represent the action. `Dictionary<string, Action()> ActionDictionary;` but it isn't checked for existence compile time. So search for the underlaying conn. between parameters

Comment: A dictionary would also be pretty similar to the class approach like @JeroenvanLangen said; you wouldn't need a whole class in this case

Comment: I'd rather use a class, because of the compiletime check. You don't want the `KeyNotFoundException` of a dictionary.

Comment: You could create an abstract class implementing the `public StrategyDelegate OpenWindow();` and derive from that class. The instance of the derived class could be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a many delegates as arguments of a constructor doesn't sounds like a best practice. Passing them as a `List<delegate>` might be even worse to me. It bring some extra risks with it. But that shouldn't be a problem.

What if you try to pass a class as a parameter:

```
public class MyActions
{
    public StrategyDelegate OpenWindow { get; set; }
    public StrategyDelegate CloseWindow { get; set; }
}
```

But that means the methods (declared as properties here) can be changed whenever you want. You could change it a struct, so it will create a copy, so the actions cannot be changed after passing them to the constructor.

---

I think I would go for inheritance, if the delegates aren't changed while running:

I would create an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract void OpenWindow();
    public abstract void CloseWindow();  // <-- at least pass a object sender?
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override void OpenWindow()
    { 
        // you code:
    }

    public override void CloseWindow()
    {
        // you code:
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ViewConfiguration 
{
    public MyBaseClass _myBaseClass;

    public ViewConfiguration(MyBaseClass myBaseClass)
    {
        _myBaseClass = myBaseClass;
    }


    public void CloseWindow()
    {
        _myBaseClass?.CloseWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with this answer - What if my class already has another base class? I using winforms and this is a View, so it has a Form as a base class already. How would you go about it with this restriction?

Comment: @Fillioiliu You could use interfaces for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Class that has a whole bunch of set methods for the different delegates you want to pass to View from Controller; simple example with primitive types:

```
public class ViewConfiguration {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public string c;
    public bool d;

    public ViewConfiguration setA(int newA) {
        // setB, setC, and setD will follow a similar structure
        a = newA;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then Controller can make a configuration as follows:

```
var config = new ViewConfiguration();
// you can do any combination/order of these
config.setA(2).setB(4).setC("hello").setD(true);
```

Then you can pass `config` into View, and View can simply do `config.a`.  You should probably make it so that only getting is public with properties (hide directly setting fields behind the set methods), but this is a general idea.

Comment: Why not create a method where you set them all at ones? or using properties?

Comment: A method with all the parameters would be just as long as the constructor with all the parameters.  Properties should almost always be used as well, I didn't in this example though.

Comment: The difference is that you can enforce all values with the constructor.

Comment: And you can enforce the values with the setters too.  It's mostly a preference choice.  The main problem is using a list, as you pointed out in the comments above.